# Confirming lazy evaluation

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

I accidentally deleted my post, but I'm reposting this question for clarification.

If I have a function:
`const x = 1`

If I ask Haskell:
`const (1/0)`

It will return `1` because lazy evaluation doesn't actually calculate what `1/0` is, right? It doesn't need to.

Comment: Yeah, that's what Haskell's non-strict semantic guarantees.

Comment: Note that `1/0` does not actually throw an exception - it just returns a special `Double` value. But if you change it to something that _does_ throw an exception (e.g., `error "die"`), you still get `1` as the answer.

Comment: Of course, `const` is a bad name for this – you could call it `const1`, and it could in fact be defined as `const1 = const 1`. The name `const`, like most Prelude functions, should not be used for anything else.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, that's right. `const`, as you defined it, will always produce 1 when it is evaluated - no matter what the argument is. And since the argument is not relevant to the result, it is not evaluated. Thus any error or non-termination that might be caused by evaluating the argument will not occur.